# Month over Day pivot table in Quicksight

Tags: pivot-table, visualization, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field, bi-tool

I have a pivot table visual that shows website visits. It has a list of prefectures as rows and daily dates as columns. The numbers in the table represent the number of visits.
I want to show the difference between the daily visits and the visits for an entire month (for example, June 2023) next to each number.

I tried with `periodOverPeriodDifference` function but that doesn't seem to fit my needs.

I also attempted to create a calculated field that includes values only from a specific month, like June 2023. Then, I used this calculated field to subtract the daily values. However, the results are only visible in the columns corresponding to June 2023 columns in the table.